# Confusion about the behaviour of multiple seeds of ConfidenceConnected image filter. More seeds, bigger area?

Tags: region, seed, itk

I am using SimpleITK's `VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter`. I feel confused about its behaviour when multiple seeds are provided.

I am doing 3D segmentation of bile duct. Firstly I got a probability map using SVM (Pairwise Coupling). Then I got 228 points whose probability are more than 0.999999. Using these 228 points as seeds, I got NOTHING from the `VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter`. By the way, the 228 seeds may be located very close to each other. Here are some seeds for example.

```
Seed information: 
Seed_index      Seed_x_y_z      prob    CT_value_a      CT_value_b
0,      (161, 241, 163),        0.9999991059303284,     24,     19
1,      (161, 242, 163),        0.9999989867210388,     33,     23
2,      (203, 215, 164),        0.999999463558197,      3,      7
3,      (161, 241, 164),        0.9999989867210388,     28,     22
4,      (162, 242, 164),        0.9999989867210388,     35,     24
5,      (161, 241, 165),        0.9999991059303284,     27,     22
6,      (162, 241, 165),        0.9999992847442627,     30,     25
7,      (162, 242, 165),        0.9999992251396179,     31,     22
8,      (162, 242, 166),        0.9999991059303284,     33,     27
9,      (165, 241, 169),        0.9999992251396179,     24,     26
10,     (166, 241, 170),        0.9999994039535522,     12,     25
11,     (166, 242, 170),        0.9999996423721313,     15,     19
12,     (167, 242, 170),        0.9999997019767761,     14,     22
13,     (165, 243, 170),        0.9999990463256836,     15,     20
14,     (166, 243, 170),        0.9999996423721313,     13,     20
15,     (167, 243, 170),        0.9999991655349731,     21,     16
16,     (166, 241, 171),        0.9999995827674866,     11,     19
17,     (167, 241, 171),        0.9999996423721313,     7,      23
18,     (166, 242, 171),        0.9999992251396179,     7,      14
19,     (167, 242, 171),        0.9999998211860657,     11,     13
20,     (168, 242, 171),        0.9999997615814209,     12,     19
21,     (168, 243, 171),        0.9999991059303284,     16,     11
22,     (150, 297, 171),        0.9999990463256836,     61,     56
23,     (149, 208, 172),        0.9999992847442627,     45,     38
24,     (149, 209, 172),        0.999999463558197,      45,     35
25,     (167, 240, 172),        0.9999989867210388,     13,     28
26,     (166, 241, 172),        0.9999993443489075,     10,     19
27,     (167, 241, 172),        0.9999992251396179,     9,      13
...
```

Covariance matrix when using the first 25 seeds:

```
Covariance matrix: 
[[ nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan]]
```

How could I get `nan` in the covariance matrix?

Then I tried to use fewer seeds.
Using the first 5 seeds I can get some segmentation result. Using the first 20 seeds I can also get some segmentation result. The segmented area seems smaller but is not the subset of the previously segmented area. When I use the first 25 seeds, I got NOTHING segmented.

How could this happen?

Shouldn't it be more seed, more and bigger the grown area?

By the way, the setting of `numberOfIterations` and `multiplier` are always the same.

```
numberOfIterations=4, multiplier=3.5
```

I read the document (https://itk.org/SimpleITKDoxygen/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter.html#details) and found nothing to explain this.

PS:

What I want to segment is bile duct. When the output is normal, the segmented area will be marked with value 1. By "the output is nothing", I mean all of the voxels, even the ones I use as seeds, are marked with 0 and therefore nothing is segmented.

The official explanation for the filter is what happens for a single seed point. What happens when I input multiple seed points? I input 2 seeds and change their order. I found the order of input seeds matters. The output segmented area is connected with the first seed but may not be connected with the second seed.

I want to limit the number of seeds and want the region grow from most trust-worthy points. So I use 0.999999 to threshold seed points. Actually, the output using the first 5 seeds is real promising. But I don't know why more seeds, smaller (but not the subset) the output region becomes.

After I changed the parameters to

```
numberOfIterations=2, multiplier=2.5
```

Using first 25 seeds will be OK. However, the segmented result is far bigger than I want. Almost 1/2 of the output volume is marked with 1.

PS2 (added as suggested by @blowekamp):
The settings of parameters:

```
seed_vol = sitk.Image(seg.GetSize(), sitk.sitkUInt8)
seed_vol.CopyInformation(seg)
for seed in seeds_xyz[0:25]:
    seed_vol[seed] = 1
filter = sitk.VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter()
filter.SetSeedList(seeds_xyz[0:25])
filter.SetMultiplier(2.5)
stat_filter = sitk.LabelStatisticsImageFilter()
for iteration in range(0,5):
    filter.SetNumberOfIterations(iteration)
    seg = filter.Execute(img_multi)
    print("Number of iteration: {0}".format(iteration))
    print("Mean from VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter: {0}".format(filter.GetMean()))
    print("Covariance matrix from VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter:")
    print((nine_ele_list_to_matrix(filter.GetCovariance())))
    stat_filter.Execute(predicted_prob_vol, seg)
    print("Mean from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for grown output: {0}".format(stat_filter.GetMean(1)))
    print("Covariance from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for grown output: {0}".format(stat_filter.GetVariance(1)))
    print("The labels: {0}. Label count of statistics filter: {1}".format(stat_filter.GetLabels(), stat_filter.GetNumberOfLabels()))
    stat_filter.Execute(predicted_prob_vol, seed_vol)
    print("Mean from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for seeds: {0}".format(stat_filter.GetMean(1)))
    print("Covariance from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for seeds: {0}".format(stat_filter.GetVariance(1)))
    print()
```

The output:

```
Number of iteration: 0
Mean from VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter: (0.9623870230024614, 31.73925925925926, 25.998518518518512)
Covariance matrix from VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter:
[[  1.82135131e-02  -7.92697795e-01  -3.38983449e-01]
 [ -7.92697795e-01   1.18911385e+02   5.24617833e+01]
 [ -3.38983449e-01   5.24617833e+01   4.07701509e+01]]
Mean from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for grown output: 0.8556543207298526
Covariance from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for grown output: 0.029425739235467253
The labels: (0, 1). Label count of statistics filter: 2
Mean from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for seeds: 0.9999993205070495
Covariance from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for seeds: 7.25345709421769e-14

Number of iteration: 1
Mean from VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter: (0.8556543207298526, 28.868118168903834, 20.2249441915751)
Covariance matrix from VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter:
[[  2.94248861e-02  -9.82479976e-01  -5.38478238e-01]
 [ -9.82479976e-01   3.63929118e+02   2.06866705e+02]
 [ -5.38478238e-01   2.06866705e+02   1.56397694e+02]]
Mean from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for grown output: 0.03871633721462062
Covariance from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for grown output: 0.02691964569621114
The labels: (0, 1). Label count of statistics filter: 2
Mean from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for seeds: 0.9999993205070495
Covariance from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for seeds: 7.25345709421769e-14

Number of iteration: 2
Mean from VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter: (0.038716337214620644, 55.72496796726461, 36.093515782149844)
Covariance matrix from VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter:
[[  2.69196225e-02  -8.70168501e-01  -5.37384540e-01]
 [ -8.70168501e-01   2.78522779e+02   1.66893233e+02]
 [ -5.37384540e-01   1.66893233e+02   1.27068694e+02]]
Mean from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for grown output: 0.0
Covariance from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for grown output: 0.0
The labels: (0,). Label count of statistics filter: 1
Mean from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for seeds: 0.9999993205070495
Covariance from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for seeds: 7.25345709421769e-14

Number of iteration: 3
Mean from VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter: (nan, nan, nan)
Covariance matrix from VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter:
[[ nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan]]
Mean from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for grown output: 0.0
Covariance from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for grown output: 0.0
The labels: (0,). Label count of statistics filter: 1
Mean from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for seeds: 0.9999993205070495
Covariance from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for seeds: 7.25345709421769e-14

Number of iteration: 4
Mean from VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter: (nan, nan, nan)
Covariance matrix from VectorConfidenceConnectedImageFilter:
[[ nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan]]
Mean from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for grown output: 0.0
Covariance from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for grown output: 0.0
The labels: (0,). Label count of statistics filter: 1
Mean from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for seeds: 0.9999993205070495
Covariance from LabelStatisticsImageFilter for seeds: 7.25345709421769e-14
```

As for the initialNeighborhoodRadius, I didn't set it manually. According to the words from the document,

> "The mean and variance across a neighborhood (8-connected,
>   26-connected, etc.) are calculated for a seed point. "

. By default, isn't it 26-connected neighborhood?

Also, there is something called 'initial segmentation from the seed point' in the official document. How multiple seeds are managed in the algorithm? Is it something like first-in-first-out queue initialized using multiple seeds? For confidence connected image filter, there is something can be seen as **initial growing criterion** defined by using mean and standard deviation of neighbors of seed point. When I am using multiple seeds, is this initial criterion generated from only the first seed or all the seeds unbiasedly?

Comment: Try running the filter over a set of iterations [0,1...4]. After then get the Covariance, and Mean from the filter, and run the LabelStatisticsImageFilter to look at the statistics of the output. Because you probability image is so small you are likely running into numeric stability issues with such a small variance. What is the variance of your seeds? Also have you looked into the InitialNeighborhoodRadius parameter?

Comment: @blowekamp, thanks. I post these things in the PS2 part of my question. Please have a look at that.

Comment: Can you please add the label statistic filter too?

Comment: @blowekamp I added the output of label statistic filter for all iterations. Please have a look at that. I am wondering the way multiple seeds are managed in the confidence connected filter (See the last paragraph of my question). Because I feel the order of seeds really matters, especially when the intensities of seeds differs from each other considerably.

Comment: I was interested in the count of the labels from the statistics filter too. I am suspicions that you may for the Nan or Inf in you vector image.

Comment: @blowekamp : I have changed the code to output the count of the labels from the statistics filter. I have used `numpy.isfinite` to check `Nan` and `Inf` for my vector image img_multi. And there is no `Nan` or `Inf` in it.

Comment: Thank you from your persistence with trying to understand this issue. You may have discovered a bug. Can you reproduce the problem on a small crop of your data? Can you share your data?

Comment: I upload the data and code to reproduct the problem here. Please have a look at it.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-bBLDhQOellekhsdG0zRkd3M0U?usp=sharing

Comment: @blowekamp : If you cannot download the data, please let me know. I will send it in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a couple problems.

1) You say the output is nothing. The expected output is an image of 0's and 1's. If that image is directly displayed many views will show only a black image. A simple visualization may be to multiple by 255, or you could use the LabelToRGBImageFilter. Additionally you could run the LabelStatisticsImageFilter.

2) This does not appear to be the correct filter for your input and usage. The documentation for this filter says:

> This filter extracts a connected set of pixels whose pixel intensities
>   are   consistent with the pixel statistics of a seed point. The mean
>   and variance across a neighborhood (8-connected, 26-connected, etc.)
>   are calculated for a seed point. Then pixels connected to this seed
>   point whose values are within the confidence interval for the seed
>   point are grouped.

This means that if you give it only pixel with >0.999, then the estimated mean and variance will be very tight and the region will not grow much. Again you can use the LabelStatisticsImageFilter to compute statistics of the intensities under the label image.

Using the ConnectedThresholdImageFilter with manually setting the lower threshold bounds, may be more appropriate. You may also look into the DoubleThresholdImageFilter which does these two steps (selecting seeds by threshold, then growing the region to a threshold) in one filter.

Comment: Thank you for your replying. I added "PS:" to my question to respond to you. Please read that. The setting of numberOfIterations=4, multiplier=3.5 will make the region grow efficiently when given a single seed. But when I use more seeds, the region gets smaller and smaller.